# Get Element Before Self

Tags: c#, xml, lambda, linq-to-xml

If the current "Name" element is null or empty it should take the "Name" value of the previous element. The very first element name will never be null or empty.

I need to get the previous elements "Name" value where the current "Name" element value is null or empty:

```
List<ScripTbl> ScripData = ScrpHldNode.Descendants(ns + "Scrp").Select(x => new ScripTbl
{
    ID = sID,
    //need help with the line below....
    ScripShare = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((String)x.Element(ns + "Name")) ? (String)x.Element(ns + "Name") : (x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count() > 0 ? (String)x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Last().Element(ns + "Name") : "")),
    ScripOpenBalanceDue = (String)x.Element(ns + "OpBal"),
    ScripClosingBalance = (String)x.Element(ns + "ClBal"),
    ScripTransaction = (String)x.Element(ns + "Tran"),
    ScripMovement = (String)x.Element(ns + "Move"),
    ScripFooter = sScripFooter,
    Seq = x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count() + 1,
    ScripSectorCode = (String)x.Element(ns + "SecCde"),
    ScripClosingPrice = (String)x.Element(ns + "ClPrce"),
    SplitIndicator = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((String)x.Element(ns + "Name")) ? (x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count() > 0 && (String)x.Element(ns + "Name") == (String)x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Last().Element(ns + "Name") ? "1" : "0") : "0")
}).ToList();
```

and the XML:

```
<ScrpHld xmlns="http://www.website.co.za/namespace">
<Scrp>
    <Name>Company Name Number 1</Name>
    <SecCde>1366J</SecCde>
    <Tran>SOLD</Tran>
    <OpBal>0</OpBal>
    <Move>-2000</Move>
</Scrp>
<Scrp>
    <Tran>ELECTRONIC SETTLEMENT</Tran>
    <Move>2000</Move>
    <ClPrce>25045.00</ClPrce>
    <ClBal>0</ClBal>
</Scrp>
<Scrp>
    <Name>Company Name Number 2</Name>
    <SecCde>1313J</SecCde>
    <Tran>SOLD</Tran>
    <OpBal>10000</OpBal>
    <Move>-90500</Move>
</Scrp>
<Scrp>
    <Tran>ELECTRONIC SETTLEMENT</Tran>
    <Move>80500</Move>
    <ClPrce>3392.00</ClPrce>
    <ClBal>0</ClBal>
</Scrp> 
</ScrpHld>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `PreviousNode` instead of `ElementsBeforeSelf`, it will be easier. I splited into multiple lines just for increase the readability of the answer.

The line should look similar to this

```
ScripShare = (x.Element(ns + "Name") != null 
                 ? (string)x.Element(ns + "Name")
                 : (x.PreviousNode != null
                          ? ((XElement)x.PreviousNode).Element(ns + "Name").Value
                          : string.Empty)),
```

If your xml will contain comments or any other text within  elements, you should check that previous node is of type `XElement` and not a coment (`XComent`) or a text (`XText`), then in this case it will be easy using `ElementsBeforeSelf`

```
ScripShare = (x.Element(ns + "Name") != null 
                     ? (string)x.Element(ns + "Name")
                     : (x.NodesBeforeSelf().Last(e => e.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) != null
                              ? ((XElement)x.NodesBeforeSelf().Last(e => e.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)).Element(ns + "Name").Value
                              : string.Empty)),
```

Comment: 'System.Xml.Linq.XNode' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XNode' could be found

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to cast PreviousNode to XElement, I've updated the answer

Comment: Unable to cast object of type System.Xml.Linq.XText to type System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Comment: I am testing it right now and it works, are you sure is not something else? Why PreviousNode is XText? it should be of type XNode.

Comment: I guess you are testing it with a different xml. It seems you have a text before any of the <Scrp> elements. Is this a valid scenario?

Comment: Other than the ScrpHld node at the start and end there should no other text. There will be a lot more Scrp nodes(I just pasted a couple as an example)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private static string ns = "{http://www.website.co.za/namespace}";
    private static string getName(XElement x) {
        if (x == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("First elements has no Name");
        var val = (string) x.Element(ns + "Name");
        return val ?? getName((XElement)x.PreviousNode);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<ScrpHld xmlns=""http://www.website.co.za/namespace"">
        <Scrp>
            <Name>Company Name Number 1</Name>
            <SecCde>1366J</SecCde>
            <Tran>SOLD</Tran>
            <OpBal>0</OpBal>
            <Move>-2000</Move>
        </Scrp>
        <Scrp>
            <Tran>ELECTRONIC SETTLEMENT</Tran>
            <Move>2000</Move>
            <ClPrce>25045.00</ClPrce>
            <ClBal>0</ClBal>
        </Scrp>
        <Scrp>
            <Name>Company Name Number 2</Name>
            <SecCde>1313J</SecCde>
            <Tran>SOLD</Tran>
            <OpBal>10000</OpBal>
            <Move>-90500</Move>
        </Scrp>
        <Scrp>
            <Tran>ELECTRONIC SETTLEMENT</Tran>
            <Move>80500</Move>
            <ClPrce>3392.00</ClPrce>
            <ClBal>0</ClBal>
        </Scrp> 
        </ScrpHld>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var result = doc.Descendants(ns + "Scrp").Select(x => new
            {
                Name = getName(x)
            });
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
```

This method uses a recursive approach so even if two consecutive elements don't have a name they will have the name of the previous element.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable for capturing current name out of select method scope:

```
string name = "";
scripData = ScrpHldNode.Descendants(ns + "Scrp")
                       .Select(scrp => {
                            var currentName = (string)scrp.Element(ns + "Name");
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentName))
                                name = currentName;

                            return new ScripTbl {
                                ScripShare = name
                                // ...
                            };
                       });
```

No recursion, no traversing xml tree for previous elements.

---

If you need to check only for missing name elements, then code can be shortened to

```
string name = "";
var scripData = from scrp in ScrpHldNode.Descendants(ns + "Scrp")
                let currentName = (string)scrp.Element(ns + "Name") ?? name
                select new ScripTbl {
                     ScripShare = (name = currentName)
                     // ...
                };
```

It's shorter (due to null-coalescing operator usage and tricky name assignment during ScripShare assignment) but I'd go with longer and more obvious code.